# Accidently un-checked the synchronise check box for a folder. Now it wont let me re-check it

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

In the file browser  on the desktop I accidentally unchecked the synchronize check box for my pictures folder. It wont let me recheck it, it just says that "this folder cannot be synchronized as it contains one or more folders that is already synchronized". Ive looked on the web interface for my Ubuntu One account and the "pictures folder" and all subfolders have dissiappeared from the account.

How on earth do I get this (rather important) folder to resynchronize?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in the Ubuntu One client under "Cloud folders". You select folders to be synchronized on each computer.

The protocol is missing some features to keep Nautilus in sync with settings. For instance, if you publish a file from another computer or from the web, Nautilus will not show the file as published on other computers. Using the Ubuntu One client, you should not have problems with this.

This is a well known issue, and will likely be addressed in the future.